# In Qualtrics with Java: How to hide an answer option under certain conditions in a loop and merge

Tags: javascript, loops, hide, qualtrics

I am trying to hide the fourth option of a question in a loop and merge if one of the loop and merge fields refers to a certain name. here is the code i am using at the moment:

```js
     Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.addOnload(function()
{
 if("${lm://Field/2}"=="76ers"){
  $('QR~${lm://CurrentLoopNumber}_QID27~4').hide();
}
 
});
```

the idea is, if Field/2 is "76ers", then it should hide the fourth option of this question. I am very new to using java in qualtrics so there is a lot that could be going wrong here. The loop is randomized, and field 2 refers to an embedded data field which at some point will refer to the 76ers. I want to hide the fourth choice option when it does that - but no joy with the code I am using.

In case it helps, I attach the screen where I want is for the fourth option down to be hidden.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sOndy.jpg)

Please let me know if anyone has a solution!

Many thanks,

Josh

Comment: Is it for Java or Javascript? It is tagged as javascript but you have java in the title.

Comment: Javascript - sorry for confusion!